# Why RecyclerView in fragment is not showing any data from firebase backend?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to show posts from a Firebase db in a dashboard using RecyclerView just after a user login. I don't know whats going wrong. The RecyclerView is not getting populated. It is not showing even a single item. I searched a lot on google but no solution seems to be working.

**Post.java:**

```
public class Post {

    private String bloodGroup;
    private String postDescription;
    private String postTitle;
    private String timestamp;
    private String userId;

    public Post(){

    }

    public Post(String postTitle, String bloodGroup, String postDescription, String userId, String timestamp) {
        this.postTitle = postTitle;
        this.bloodGroup = bloodGroup;
        this.postDescription = postDescription;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }



    public String getPostTitle() {
        return postTitle;
    }

    public void setPostTitle(String postTitle) {
        this.postTitle = postTitle;
    }

    public String getBloodGroup() {
        return bloodGroup;
    }

    public void setBloodGroup(String bloodGroup) {
        this.bloodGroup = bloodGroup;
    }

    public String getPostDescription() {
        return postDescription;
    }

    public void setPostDescription(String postDescription) {
        this.postDescription = postDescription;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

**DashboardFragment.java:**

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "Dashboard_Fragment";
    private RecyclerView postsListRcview;

    View postsListView;

    DatabaseReference firebaseDbUsers, firebaseDbPosts;

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder> postsRecyclerAdapter;

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    public DashboardFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        postsListView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
        postsListView.setTag(TAG);

        initVariables();

        return postsListView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private void printMessage(String msg){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void initVariables(){

        postsListRcview = (RecyclerView) postsListView.findViewById(R.id.posts_list_rcview);
        postsListRcview.setHasFixedSize(true);

        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        postsListRcview.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        postsRecyclerAdapter = null;
        postsListRcview.setAdapter(postsRecyclerAdapter);

        firebaseDbUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");
        firebaseDbPosts = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Post");

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        postsRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(

                Post.class,
                R.layout.posts_rcview_item,
                PostViewHolder.class,
                firebaseDbPosts

        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, Post model, int position) {

                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getPostTitle());
                printMessage("Hello");

            }
        };

        postsRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        postsListRcview.setAdapter(postsRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        View mView;
        TextView postTitleTv;
        TextView requesterNameTv;
        ImageView requesterPropic;
        TextView timestampTv;

        public PostViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title){

            postTitleTv = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title_tv);
            postTitleTv.setText(title);
        }

        public void setRequesterName(String name){
            requesterNameTv = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.requester_name_tv);
            requesterNameTv.setText(name);
        }

        public void setRequesterPropic(Context context, String path){
            requesterPropic = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.requester_propic_imgview);
            Picasso.with(context).load(path).into(requesterPropic);
        }

        public void setTimestamp(String timestamp){
            timestampTv = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp_tv);
            timestampTv.setText(timestamp);
        }
    }
}
```

**Firebase Database:**

[image]

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is a code, which is responsible to fetch data from Firebase

Comment: Update your adapter code too

Comment: @Rahul In DashboardFragment.java there is an adapter in onStart() method.

Comment: You have to point to your keys like - KpzG9VEWSV

Comment: @PhátPhát I am a newbie. So can you help me please to update? I just know that I have to set the "ViewHolder" properties using the model object.

Comment: @Rahul Can you please give me an example? I am new to it.

Comment: Try once with FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Post").child("kpzG9VEWFSV8CHwc69J"); Try with this and let me know. Please cross verify key

Comment: @Rahul Ok I will try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The problem was in the Post class. The type of the member variable "timestamp" in Post.java was String but in Firebase the datatype was long. So it was the problem to retrieve the data. I simply changed the datatype of "timestamp" variable from String to long. Another problem was the RecyclerView disappeared just after a second. I just commented the following code: `postsListRcview.setHasFixedSize(true);` in DashboardFragment.java. That's all. Thanks.